# How to inject CrudRepository and EntityManager from secondary DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to initialize two `DataSource` in my app, as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource2")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the secondary datasource explicit as follows:

```
public class SecondaryDbService {
   @Autowired
   private EntityManager em;

   @Autowired
   private SecondaryCrudRepository dao;
}

interface SecondaryCrudRepository implements CrudRepository<SecondaryEntity, Long> {
}
```

If configured as above, the service would use the *primary* datasource.

Question: how can I tell the `CrudRepository` to rely on the "secondaryDataSource"? And likewise, how can I inject the `EntityManager` from the "secondaryDataSource"?

Comment: For the Datasources / EntityManger you can use the `@Qualifier`-Annotation. To specify which one you want to inject

Comment: Yes, but how is the name of the secondary `EntityManager` or `TransactionManager`? I assume they are probably implicit build when creating a `@Bean` of the secondary ds?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helping, but maybe have a look at [routing datasources](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Comment: Or would I additionally have to build the `EntityManager` and `TxManager` myself? The blogpost does not help as I'm not using a `JdbcTemplate` here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use multiple datasources, the key is to have the configurations for each Datasource in different packages. You will need to separate your entities between these packages according to which datasource they should access.

You will also have to implement both entity and transaction managers for each datasource in these packages.

To much theory ? in practical it would look something like this:

```
com.package1
- com.package1.entities
   - EntityClass1.java (annotated with @Entity)
- ConfigForDataSource1.java

com.package2
- com.package2.entities
   - EntityClass2.java (annotated with @Entity)
- ConfigForDataSource2.java
```

Here's how ConfigForDataSource1 would look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerDataSource1",
    basePackages = "com.package1",
    transactionManagerRef = "TransactionManagerDataSource1")
public class MasterDBConfig {

   @Bean(name="DataSource1")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource1.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }

   @Bean(name="entityManagerDataSource1")
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerDataSource1(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,@Qualifier("DataSource1") DataSource dataSource) {
       return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.package1").persistenceUnit("DataSource1").build();
    }

   @Bean(name = "TransactionManagerDataSource1")
   public PlatformTransactionManager TransactionManagerDataSource1(@Qualifier("entityManagerDataSource1") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
       return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
   }
}
```

Then do the same for package 2 and enjoy.

Good luck !

Comment: Indeed one has to build the ds, txmanager and emf explicit when multiple databases should be used.